# Change of font in my moderncv CV

Tags: fonts, moderncv

When I recompile my CV that I last changed in August 2017 I suddenly get a different font.

Old font: [image: Old font]

New font: [image: New font]

How do I get the old font back?

Here's the preamble of my CV:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
```

**EDIT 1:**

- [Log file for a build that used the font I want](https://pastebin.com/KAu98Svs)
- [Log file for a build that uses the new, undesired font](https://pastebin.com/RcU8VkxL)

**EDIT 2:**

Here's a compilable example extracted from my cv:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\firstname{Simon}
\familyname{Jakobi}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\linewidth}
\makecvtitle
\section{Studium}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you compile? Maybe you have compiled with pdfLaTeX the last time and now used a different engine? But without a minimal compilable example, it is hard to help you here. (Btw: Do you have the log file of *both* runs?)

Comment: @TeXnician: I have added log files. Can you tell what fonts were used in these builds? Apparently I always used `pdflatex`. I can try to make a compilable example, but that would be quite a bit of work since I don't want to share the info in my CV.

Comment: Surely you can just take your CV, remove all personal information and add a few bogus definitions to show the fonts.

Comment: The old CV loaded `tgpagella` (TeX Gyre Pagella), the new one doesn't.

Comment: @moewe: I have extracted a small example. Do you know how I can make my cv use Pagella again?

Comment: @sjakobi The banking style automatically uses `tgpagella`, iff it is installed. You had the font installed in your old TeX installation but not in the current one. Just install the `tex-gyre` package using your package manager.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger: Lovely, that solves it! Thanks everyone!

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I would like to ask you to write up a short answer instead of closing. The behaviour of the class is unusual enough that this could confuse more people. I personally think `\IfFileExsits` for package loading is not a great idea and will file a feature request to drop it.

Comment: @moewe Good point, I will do so. When writing the feature request  you should not expect a fast response, there hasn't been any activity from xdanaux in the last years.

Comment: Submitted to https://github.com/xdanaux/moderncv/issues/73.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "old font" is the standard font of the `banking` style in `moderncv`, TeX Gyre Pagella.
You do not have to write anything in your tex file to activate it, but it has to be installed.

Sadly `moderncv` uses a trick to avoid issuing an error message if the font is not found, so the only indication that the font is missing is the automatic fallback to the "new font" (This is the TeX standard font Computer Modern).

To install "TeX Gyre Pagella" depends on your system. According to your log file you use Debian or Ubuntu, so you have to install the package named `tex-gyre`.

Open a shell window and run

```
sudo apt-get install tex-gyre
```

then follow the instructions from `apt-get`.
Afterwards compiling your document gives the right font again.