# Changing the font based on availability to fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I would like to distribute a class that uses a professional font loaded via fontspec, and falls back to one of the default fonts in TeX Live if this is not available. I know that one can detect fonts packaged with TeX Live:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\IfFileExists{tgpagella.sty}{\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}}{}

\begin{document}

\fontname\font\ at \the\fontdimen6\font

\end{document}
```

This doesn't work, however, if one instead tries to detect a font file in the same directory:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\IfFileExists{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}{\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}}{}

\begin{document}

\fontname\font\ at \the\fontdimen6\font

\end{document}
```

Is there a mechanism somewhere to include `.otf` files in what `\IfFileExists` is able to detect?

Comment: fontspec has a fallback mechanism these days [older answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250336/how-can-you-check-if-fontspec-with-lualatex-can-load-a-font/250350#250350) but Will added a proper interface to that if I recall correctly

Comment: `\fontspec_font_if_exist:nTF` and similar commands look to be the right thing....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the documentation suggests `\IfFontExistsTF`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but it looks much more impressive with `_` and `:`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Only for people not really used to `_` and `:` ;-).

Comment: Note that silently loading a different font to avoid an error can seriously confuse people, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446425/35864 for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Recent `fontspec` releases allow you to test for a font being loadable with `\IfFontExistsTF` or its internal `expl3` version `\fontspec_font_if_exist:nTF`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\IfFontExistsTF{texgyrepagella-regular.otf}{\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}}{}

\begin{document}

\fontname\font\ at \the\fontdimen6\font

\end{document}
```