# Package detection without installation in MiKTeX

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

Lately I've been using a W<s>eird</s>indows machine, in which I installed MiKTeX. Finding my way through its automatic package installer I noticed that if I check the existence of a package file which I know for sure I don't have installed:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\IfFileExists{abntex2.cls}{Oh, no!}{Phew :)}
\end{document}
```

MikTeX will install *that* package and the test will return true. Of course, that is perfectly reasonable (the installation, not the package), since `\IfFileExists` opens the file for reading to test its existence, and once it opens the file MiKTeX will try to install it.

To avoid that I can use the `--disable-installer` option which, unsurprisingly, will disable the automatic package installer. However I'd like to know if there is (or if I can make) a macro-level interface which allows me to check if a package is installed or if it's a candidate for installation without triggering the automatic installation of the package. Preferably regardless of the current setting of the package manager. Is it possible?

Comment: I reckon, you'd need some form of flag to inquire against, so the check returns true or false in either case.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I have just installed some `hyperbar` package using `\pdffilemoddate{hyperbar.sty}`. Apparently Windows _is_ excessive ;-) Apparently _any_ file operation triggers the package manager...

Comment: You can always use LuaTeX...

Comment: @MarcelKrüger I'd like engine independence, if it's possible. But if you (of course you do) know how to do it in LuaTeX, please write it down :)

Comment: if any `\openin0=full/path/to/my/file.sty \ifeof0 y\else no\fi`

Comment: @touhami Hm... Interesting point. Apparently if the full path is given then MiKTeX doesn't try to install the package. However this brings up the problem of knowing what is the full path to the file...

Comment: The thing is that `kpsewhich <package-file>` will immediately trigger auto-install if for the package to which `<package-file>` belongs. It stands to reason that any TeX-operation on the file will trigger the auto-install. So Lua or some shell escape (but don't use `kpsewhich`) seem like the only options out. ...

Comment: ... If I'm allowed the comment, I'd like to state that I'm very strongly opposed to `\IfFileExists` for loading packages or classes (not sure if that is what you have in mind and what you are doing to do in the true and false branches ...). If you want the package `\RequirePackage` it; if you don't need, it it to the user to load it. Otherwise you end up with unpredictable behaviour like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/446425/35864.

Comment: @moewe From this adventure I understood that `kpsewhich` only triggers the auto-install if the file is not found, and if the file is a valid candidate for installation. The first condition allows for what Marcel did in his answer. If you create an empty `hyperbar.sty` and do `kpsewhich hyperbar.sty`, the auto-install won't start (with or without `-all`). What I think could be another solution to the issue is the second condition: how does it know that `hyperbar.sty` is to be installed but not `hyperfoo.sty`, and if that knowledge would be available at the macro level.

Answer (score 3):

In this answer I will assume a Lua supporting engine (LuaTeX, HarfTeX, etc.)

MiKTeX is very eager to install packages, so you have to fool it:
If the file you are looking for already exists in your current directory, MiKTeX is happy and does not install the package if you ask it for the file.

So that's the plan:
Place a dummy file in the current working directory. Then ask MiKTeX, though the kpathsea emulation, for *all* known files matching the name. Of course the first one will be the local dummy file, but if another one is found, the package was installed.
Then delete the dummy file in the end.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newluafunction\filereallyexistsfuncid
\directlua{
local truetok, falsetok = token.create'@firstoftwo', token.create'@secondoftwo'
lua.get_functions_table()[\the\filereallyexistsfuncid] = function()
  local filename = token.scan_string()
  local f = io.open(filename) % First test if the file exists in the current folder
  if f then
    f:close()
    return token.put_next(truetok) % In this case we are done, the file exists
  end
  f = io.open(filename, "w") f:close() % Otherwise create it to stop MiKTeX from installing anything
  local _, f2 = kpse.lookup(filename,{all=true}) % Now we will always find the local file first and MiKTeX is happy. If the file existed before, it will be found too.
  os.remove(filename) % The local file did it's job, delete it
  token.put_next(f2 and truetok or falsetok) % And write the answer to TeX
end
}
\newcommand\filereallyexists{\luafunction\filereallyexistsfuncid}
\begin{document}
\filereallyexists{hyperbar.sty}{AWESOME!}{How can you be so cruel?}
\end{document}
```

A remark about the more special Lua language constructs here:
`kpse.lookup` returns, if `all=true`, one return value for every found file. So if only one file is found, only one value is returned. If two are found, two values, .... The line

```
local _, f2 = kpse.lookup(...)
```

stores the first two return values in the variables `_` and `f2`. (In Lua `_` is a regular variable but by convention `_` is used if a value is to be ignored) The actual values stored there are the full absolute filenames of the found files. But what happens if only one file is found? Then there are no "first two return values", only one filename is returned. In cases like this, Lua sets the remaining variables to the special value `nil`.

In our code the only important question is: Is `f2` a string or `nil`? In Lua, *every* string (including the empty string `""`) is considered true but `nil` is considered `false`.
So we can act as if `f2` was a boolean. Which brings us to the last line:

```
token.put_next(f2 and truetok or falsetok)
```

The `a and b or c` is the Lua equivalent to the tertiary conditional operator `a ? b : c` from C: If `a` (in our case `f2`) is `true`, we get `b` (`truetok`) otherwise `c` (`falsetok`). This works as long as `b` is never `false` (or `nil`) as a consequence of the short-circuiting of Lua's `and` and `or`:
We have `a and b or c` which is seen as `(a and b) or c`. If `a` is considered `true`, then `a and b` if and only if `b`. So Lua just evaluates `a and b` to `b` *without casting this to a boolean value*. We assumed `b` to be true, so `(a and b) or c === b or c` is always `true` and `c` doesn't even have to be evaluated, so Lua just returns `b`, again without casting to booleans.
So Lua's `and` and `or` *always* return the first argument which determines their truth value. (What happens for a `false` value `a` is left as an exercise to the reader ;-) )

Comment: `AWESOME!` Thanks ;-)

Comment: I understood most of what you did there. What didn't quite sink in is the last line in the Lua code, namely the expression `f2 and truetok or falsetok`. If I understood correctly `truetok` and `falsetok` are the control sequences `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo`. I didn't quite get what is `f2` (a string, a bool, etc.), and how it makes that expression evaluate to `truetok` or `falsetok`. Would you mind explaining, please?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik It's basically the second hit of the search (with the first one being the local file) and the and/or comstruction is Lua's ternary operator, so outputs truetok if f2 is not nil and falsetok otherwise.

Comment: I added some explanations, but it's exactly what TeXnician said.

Comment: @TeXnician and Marcel -- Thank you both for the explanations!